# Emacs recover-session: which session should I recover?

Tags: recover

My OS locked up while using Emacs.
So I hard boot, reopen Emacs, and M-x recover-session.
The OS locked up at Jul 6 3:05, there are two autosave sessions at 03:04

[image]

Which of the two 3:04 sessions should I use?

Also, please explain the right column.
What do the blue "site" and "dist" mean?
What does red strike-through mean?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site/  contains files for many old buffers.
When I tried to recover "site":

```
Read error: is a directory, /.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/site
```

~/.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/dist/  is empty.
When I tried to recover "dist":

```
Read error: is a directory, /.emacs.d/.cache/auto-save/dist
```

I recovered the session 14543-localhost.localdomain, using C-c C-c.